# Apache2.4.6 and wstunnel don't correct proxy to tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, apache-2.4, tomcat7

I have everything being proxy correctly just that my websockets keep giving me an unexpected 200 response error. I am using native websockets on chrome and firefox.

my conf file looks like this

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
ServerName example.com
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /websocket/ ws://localhost:8080/XXXXX/websocket/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse /websocket/ ws://localhost:8080/XXXXX/websocket/ retry=0
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/XXXXX/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/XXXXX/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /XXXXX /
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the exact error.

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

Any help would be great, I can't remove apache.

Comment: What have you done yourself to try and diagnose the problem?

Comment: @DrewKhoury when I first encountered the problem, I quickly set up test and ncat to see what was actually being passed. I then googled around for the specific error, and I came to the conclusion that the proxy part was not sending it as an upgraded connection on http 1.1. I have just been trying to figure out why apache wouldn't do that, and not many people have actually encountered this issue.